# Python Panda Error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to learn how to use Pandas in Python. I am having issue doing math to my Panda dataframe.
Right now my dataframe looks something like this:

print (mark)

```
                0      1      2       3       4           5             6
0       447366345  -2.04  -2.69  176.98  418.84  34.3167521  -118.4068498
1       447406197  -2.34  -2.18  176.88  418.77  34.3167522  -118.4068499
2       447446155  -2.63  -1.56  176.74  418.77  34.3167522  -118.4068499
3       447486653  -2.89  -0.95  176.58  418.84  34.3167522  -118.4068499
4       447526241  -3.12  -0.42  176.43  418.84  34.3167522  -118.4068499
5       447566373  -3.34  -0.07  176.32  418.84  34.3167522  -118.4068497
6       447606036  -3.56   0.05  176.26  418.66  34.3167523  -118.4068497
7       447645783  -3.77  -0.03  176.28  418.66  34.3167523  -118.4068497
8       447686269  -3.95  -0.31  176.43  418.95  34.3167523  -118.4068497

def data_reader(filename, rowname):
    with open(filename, newline='') as fp:
        yield from (row[1:] for row in csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
            if row[0] == rowname)

mike = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader('data.csv', 'mike'))
```

Now let say I want to take row 0 and divide it by 1000

```
mark_time = mark[0] / 1000
```

This produces the error

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

I am guessing because current my dataframe is not considered an INT, so I went ahead and did this:

```
mark_time = float (mark[0] / 1000)
```

However, this also gave me the same error. Could someone please explain to me why?

My 2nd question is when it comes to plotting. I have learned matplotlib very well and I wanted to use it on my Panda dataframe. Currently the way I do it is this:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize= (10,10))
ax = fig1.add_subplot(311)
ax.plot(mike_time, mike[0], label='mike speed', color = 'red')
plt.legend(loc='best',prop={'size':10})
```

Could I just replace mike_time, and mike[0] with my dataframe?

Comment: cast the type `mark[0] = mark[0].astype(int)`

Comment: `float (mark[0]) / 1000` instead of `float (mark[0] / 1000)`

Comment: @MMFI got this error TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: @EdChum That worked, however, do I have to do that for every column? is there an easier way to do this for example when I am generating the dataframe?

Comment: How did you make the df in the first place? What does df.info()  show?

Comment: @EdChum <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 20074 entries, 0 to 20073
Data columns (total 7 columns):
0    20074 non-null int32
1    20074 non-null object
2    20074 non-null object
3    20074 non-null object
4    20074 non-null object
5    20074 non-null object
6    20074 non-null object
dtypes: int32(1), object(6)
memory usage: 1019.5+ KB

Comment: @EdChum I have also edited the original question with how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pandas.read_csv instead of python's csv.

There you can use the dtype argument to provide it with the correct types of data for it to use:

From pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None Data type
>   for data or columns. E.g. {'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32}
>   (unsupported with engine='python'). Use str or object to preserve and
>   not interpret dtype.

If you must parse the CSV outside pandas an importing with "from_records" you can use coerce_float=True. [Reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

> coerce_float : boolean, default False Attempt to convert values to
>   non-string, non-numeric objects (like decimal.Decimal) to floating
>   point, useful for SQL result sets

Comment: I have tried this but I keep getting an error of :TypeError: 'dtype' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. The way I have done it with this: csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True, dtype=float)

Comment: this answer is wrong, `pd.read_csv` will try to infer the dtypes by sniffing them, the OP use the `csv` module which is completely different

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pandas read_csv which will automatically assign the most appropriate type to each column. If you have any mixed type columns it will warn you. You can then run it again setting the type explicitly.

Comment: I have tried this but I keep getting an error of :TypeError: 'dtype' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. The way I have done it with this: csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True, dtype=float

Comment: You are using csv.reader which is a python function. You need to use pandas.read_csv

Comment: And you don't need the function. Just df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")