# PYTHON - Jupiter Notebook. ERROR CODE with function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

Function that adds totals for row and column of a dataframe df, and tell which column it is for the variable

```
def Find_Total_CrossTab(df,Variable_name_index):
    df.loc[:,'Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
    df=df.reset_index()
    df=df.append(df.sum(), ignore_index=True).set_index(Variable_name_index)
    return df
```

This keep returning an error code which is:  `<built-in function _abc_instancecheck> returned a result with an error set`. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

My data set is very large. I have been using cross-tabulation for it so I have used the following:

```
# Defining the dataframe
df_1=pd.crosstab(index=df["Interval of Sales"], columns=df['Type of Customer'])

# Defining the index 
name_of_index='Interval of Sales'

# Using the function
df_Cross_Table=Find_Total_CrossTab(df_1, name_of_index)
df_Cross_Table
```

The error code I have gotten is:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' and 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/interval.pyx in pandas._libs.interval.Interval.__add__()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/abc.py in __instancecheck__(cls, instance)
     97             """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
---> 98             return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)
     99 

SystemError: <built-in function _abc_instancecheck> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/interval.pyx in pandas._libs.interval.Interval.__add__()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/abc.py in __instancecheck__(cls, instance)
     97             """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
---> 98             return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)
     99 

SystemError: <built-in function _abc_instancecheck> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-bbc580caf84c> in <module>
      6 
      7 # Using the function
----> 8 df_Cross_Table=Find_Total_CrossTab(df_1, name_of_index)
      9 df_Cross_Table

<ipython-input-32-188c1525f216> in Find_Total_CrossTab(df, Variable_name_index)
      3     df.loc[:,'Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
      4     df=df.reset_index()
----> 5     df=df.append(df.sum(), ignore_index=True).set_index(Variable_name_index)
      6     return df

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in stat_func(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
  11174                 name, axis=axis, level=level, skipna=skipna, min_count=min_count
  11175             )
> 11176         return self._reduce(
  11177             f,
  11178             name,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, numeric_only, filter_type, **kwds)
   7911             values = self.values
   7912             try:
-> 7913                 result = f(values)
   7914 
   7915                 if filter_type == "bool" and is_object_dtype(values) and axis is None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in f(x)
   7863 
   7864         def f(x):
-> 7865             return op(x, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
   7866 
   7867         def _get_data(axis_matters):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in _f(*args, **kwargs)
     67             try:
     68                 with np.errstate(invalid="ignore"):
---> 69                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
     70             except ValueError as e:
     71                 # we want to transform an object array

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in nansum(values, axis, skipna, min_count, mask)
    491     elif is_timedelta64_dtype(dtype):
    492         dtype_sum = np.float64
--> 493     the_sum = values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum)
    494     the_sum = _maybe_null_out(the_sum, axis, mask, values.shape, min_count=min_count)
    495 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     36 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     37          initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 38     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     39 
     40 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

pandas/_libs/interval.pyx in pandas._libs.interval.Interval.__add__()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/abc.py in __instancecheck__(cls, instance)
     96         def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
     97             """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
---> 98             return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)
     99 
    100         def __subclasscheck__(cls, subclass):

SystemError: <built-in function _abc_instancecheck> returned a result with an error set
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code using some sample data and it worked for me. See what I did. Can you provide a sample of your dataset and mention how you called the function? I assumed that the `Variable_name_index` should be a list with the header names. If not can you say what you intended it to be?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

df
Out[1]
            num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen  Total
falcon         2          2                 10     14
dog            4          0                  2      6
spider         8          0                  1      9
fish           0          0                  8      8


def Find_Total_CrossTab(df,Variable_name_index):
    df.loc[:,'Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
    df=df.reset_index()
    df=df.append(df.sum(), ignore_index=True).set_index(Variable_name_index)
    return df
```

Once I run it, I get the following output:

```
Find_Total_CrossTab(df, ['num_legs', 'num_wings'])

Out[2]: 
                                  index  num_specimen_seen  Total
num_legs num_wings                                               
2        2                       falcon                 10     14
4        0                          dog                  2      6
8        0                       spider                  1      9
0        0                         fish                  8      8
14       2          falcondogspiderfish                 21     37
```

Comment: I have just edited the question to include what I have input and the full error code... Thank you for your answer. My dataset is very, very similar to this but is on a much larger scale

Comment: I'm inclined to think it's something to do with either your data or the way you have read the data into the csv. But it's difficult to say without seeing at least part of your data. Have you used python's in-built [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) instead of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)? Based on your error and based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40726437/11542679) I would suggest trying with the pandas function.